# Swift & Parse : UISearchbar don't work

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift, parse-platform, uisearchbar

I added "Search bar and search display controller" in object library and i added necessary functions in my tableviewcontroller. Tableviewcontroller works properly. But when i click the search bar, it gives this error

"Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'unable to dequeue a cell with identifier mysharedCell - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard'"

I checked cell identifier and no problem with that. Here is my table view code :

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("mysharedCell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as! MySharedTableViewCell

    var object: PFObject = self.noteObjects.objectAtIndex(indexPath.row) as! PFObject

    var likes:NSNumber = object["like"] as! NSNumber
    cell.mySharedTitle?.text = object["title"] as? String
    cell.mySharedText?.text = object["text"] as? String

    if let x = object["date"] as? NSDate {
        cell.mySharedDate?.text = getDateAsString(x)
    }
    else {
        cell.mySharedDate?.text = "No date!"
    }
    cell.likesCount.text? = String("\(likes)")
    return cell
}
```

And here is my search functions :

```
func searchBarTextDidEndEditing(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // Dismiss the keyboard
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    // Force reload of table data
    self.fetchAllObjects()
    self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    // Dismiss the keyboard
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    // Force reload of table data
    self.fetchAllObjects()
    self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()
}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(searchBar: UISearchBar) {

    // Clear any search criteria
    searchBar.text = ""

    // Dismiss the keyboard
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()

    // Force reload of table data
    self.fetchAllObjects()
    self.fetchAllObjectsFromLocalDatastore()

}
```

I don't see any problem. I copied this codes properly from another sample projects. I am missing something because of that. What's wrong with that code ?

Comment: is search display controller linked to a delegate ? Also inside the class are you calling UISearchBarDelegate
 e.g. 
`class TableviewController:PFQueryTableViewController, UISearchBarDelegate`

Comment: Yes, i called searchbar.delegate = self and uisearchbardelegate in viewdidappaer.

Comment: Well i had the same issue, the code seems to be fine. I solved it by going to main storyboard and checking the outlets and referencing outlets where all correct and no duplicates etc. Make sure the delegate isn't reference the searchBar, just the search display controller as this is what is going to show the new returned table view.

Comment: look at my outlets : [link]http://tinypic.com/r/xpzi2r/8[link] is it any problem here ?

Comment: Well your delegate is only referencing your tableview at the moment and not the search display controller as well, you may want to add this to start.

If you have time take a look at this tutorial/project this is how i got my search bars working in the end, (https://medium.com/swift-programming/ios-swift-parse-com-tutorial-set-up-xcode-project-part-2-of-3-31a17d1c6581)
 my mistake was rushing into it and not linking everything via the outlets, this is what mine looks like (http://tinypic.com/r/5cyjrd/8)

Comment: sorry this is my search display outlets : http://tinypic.com/r/244893c/8

Comment: Hmm, well again delegate is only linked to the tableview and not the search display controller. Otherwise play around with them and check the tutorial i sent in link as he has them set up perfectly :)

Comment: i am using uitableviewcontroller delegate. if i use pfquerytableviewcontroller , is it work ? any difference pf and ui delegate ?

Comment: PFQueryTableViewController is just a subclass of tableviewcontroller check the tutorial i sent or the docs if you want to set it up, just makes using parse easier not more effective. Wouldn't affect search bar though no

Comment: ok i'll check the doc and do it perfectly :) i hope.. thanks.

Comment: i started again and i did the same things. my code is working well except cancel button. thanks for helping :) i just have one problem. cancel button don't show up and work.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I missed search control in my query function.

Code :

```
if searchBar.text != "" {
     query.whereKey("search_text", containsString: searchBar.text.lowercaseString)
       }
```